# Need help converting date to epoch in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, epoch

I want to add a column to my table where I have a date (DD-MM-YY) to a unix timestamp.
Tried several things but none deliver the result I am looking for.
In the end I would like

Column 1  03-06-21
**Column 2**    **1622671200**

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hi @WernfriedDomscheit.
I have SELECT (enddate - to_date('01-01-70','DD-MM-YY')) * (86400) as dt FROM TABLE; or similar select (enddate - date '1906-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60 unix_style from TABLE; This just not gives the right result.

Comment: Unbelievable, did you never hear about the [Y2K-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)? Have a look at `SELECT to_char(to_date('01-01-70','DD-MM-YY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM dual` You also should consider that Unix epoche is based on UTC.